# Why cannot the absolute error in a numerical computation correct to $n$ figures be greater than half a unit in $n$-th place?

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation

I was reading *The Accuracy of Approximate Calculations* in *Numerical Analysis* by *K. Mukherjee*; there the author mentioned a **note** after introducing *absolute error* to be followed:

> **Note**: The absolute error in a numerical computation correct to $n$ significant figures **cannot** be greater than *half a unit* in $n$-th place.

Why is it so? Why cannot the absolute error be greater than "*half a unit in $n$-th place*"?

The author didn't provide any derivation or how he concluded this; is there any proof of this?

Comment: If the error were greater than that, the correct rounding to $n$ places would produce a different number.

Answer (score 1):

This is true only if default rounding mode (i.e. round to a nearest value) is used and the result do not underflow or overflow.

However according to IEEE-754 standard different rounding modes are possible, for example rounding toward $+\infty$ (ceiling) or rounding toward $-\infty$ (flooring). With these non default rounding modes it is possible, that roundoff error can be larger than half of and unit in the last place.

In general, if a number do not underflow or overflow, then roundoff error cannot be larger than unit in the last place. If a number underflows or overflows, then roundoff error can be much larger.